# Angular ng-model select option first element empty

Tags: angularjs, select

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="item.visible">
        <option value="0">NO</option>
        <option value="1">YES</option>
</select>
```

ITEM:

```
$scope.item.visible = 1; //doesn't work
$scope.item.visible = "1" //works fine
```

I absolutely don't understand why first solution doesn't work and my problem is that I'm getting this value from database and I can't change it to string. I think solution could be use a directive. But I'm sure there will be much better solution.
Thanks for help.

Comment: using `ng-options` will avoid such corner case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because Angular uses strict comparison of the model value with the value bound to option. If you can't use string value as model you could cast it in HTML with ngInit directive:

```
<select ng-model="item.visible" ng-init="item.visible=item.visible + ''">
    <option value="0">NO</option>
    <option value="1">YES</option>
</select>
```

then it will work with both `$scope.item.visible = 1;` and `$scope.item.visible = "1";`.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/kZJbVRtyHQ19LUbDALFx?p=preview